# How to remove packages from my own Debian package?

Tags: apt, package-management, debian

I know the basics of creating a Debian package. But I wish to create one that marks other packages for removal as it is installed.

Under the Debian folder of the package at the control file, I tried to put the packages that I desire to be removed under the Conflicts or Breaks field, but with no success. apt-get refuses to install my package and does not remove the packages either under conflicts or breaks...

What I'm missing? Couldn't find the appropriate directions under the Debian manuals...

Comment: I haven't created a Debian package before, but you should read this http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html (7.3 and 7.4). From what I've gathered, it seems that Conflicts and Breaks are **intended** to make `apt-get` refuse to install, unless that other package is removed or "deconfigured". I think `aptitude`'s behavior to this might be different though; I think it could try to remove those Conflicts.

Comment: In *pure theory* you can create a metapackage, and then define "Conflicts: " or "Breaks: " lines for the packages you *don't* want it to work with; you can then `apt-get install -f` or similar to force your package in and remove the others, but this could cause issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using traditional methods, however you can abuse apt-get by removing temporarily it's lock files, the approach would involve:

1. Disable temporarily apt/dpkg locks
2. Update / Install / Remove software
3. Merge changes to the dpkg database
4. Enable back apt/dpkg locks
5. Profit

### 1. Disable temporarily apt/dpkg locks

Move temporarily to another location the following files:

- /var/lib/dpkg/lock
- /var/lib/dpkg/updates/
- /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

### 2. Update / Install / Remove software

Run apt-get to install/remove software, Acknowledge that apt-get/dpkg write its state to:

- /var/lib/dpkg/status

Let's suppose you have a system with the following packages: `firefox, htop, curl`, and let's suppose that your package `foo` removes `curl`, so upon installation of your package you should have `firefox, htop, foo` however since dpkg updates its state once per instance your nested state will be overrided by the parent process leaving the following status `firefox, htop, curl, foo`

So, you won't have the curl files around but to dpkg the package will still be installed, this will also happen with new software and dependencies.

Let's suppose your `foo` packages installs `apache2` which depends in `apache2-data`, you would expect them in your dpkg database as: `firefox, htop, curl, foo, apache2, apache2-data` , however you'll have `firefox, htop, curl, foo`, the nested output was overrided by the parent process which was only aware of the installation of `foo`

### 3. Merge changes to the dpkg database

In order to avoid this mix-up, you'll need to take care of the dpkg changes manually, also since the file is overrided with other apt-get/dpkg instances you would need to save the changes in a different location and apply them to the original file **only after** the main apt-get/dpkg instance is done, since your script will end before that happen, you'll need to leave behind a cronjob entry or a hand-made daemon.

### 4. Enable back apt/dpkg locks

### 5. Profit

Since the above process can be somehow troublesome, I'm leaving a naive implementation, be sure to understand it before using it and expect corner cases.

```
package=my-pkg

_dpkg_suspend_process() {
    #unlock standard files
    busybox mv     /var/lib/dpkg/lock           /var/lib/dpkg/lock.suspended
    busybox rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates.suspended/
    busybox mv     /var/lib/dpkg/updates/       /var/lib/dpkg/updates.suspended
    busybox mkdir  /var/lib/dpkg/updates/
    busybox mv     /var/cache/apt/archives/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock.suspended

    #debconf missing file descriptors workaround
    busybox cp /usr/share/debconf/confmodule       /usr/share/debconf/confmodule.bk  
    busybox cp /usr/share/minos/debconf/confmodule /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

    #while apt is being executed it modifies the status file which brings conflicts
    #to new packages if they're installed/removed in abused apt instances, therefore
    #the status-old file (which represent the original state in which the first
    #apt instance was launched) is used to create temporal diffs which will be merged
    #at the end
    busybox cp     /var/lib/dpkg/status         /var/lib/dpkg/status.suspended
    busybox cp     /var/lib/dpkg/status-old     /var/lib/dpkg/status-orig
    busybox cp     /var/lib/dpkg/status-orig    /var/lib/dpkg/status
}

_dpkg_continue_process() {
    #relock standard files
    busybox rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates
    busybox mv     /var/lib/dpkg/lock.suspended           /var/lib/dpkg/lock
    busybox mv     /var/lib/dpkg/updates.suspended        /var/lib/dpkg/updates
    busybox mv     /var/cache/apt/archives/lock.suspended /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
    busybox mv     /var/lib/dpkg/status.suspended         /var/lib/dpkg/status

    #debconf missing file descriptors workaround
    busybox mv     /usr/share/debconf/confmodule.bk       /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

    #keep status-old file to survive multiple abused apt instances
    busybox mv     /var/lib/dpkg/status-orig              /var/lib/dpkg/status-old
}

_dpkg_sync_status_db() {
    _dpkg_sync_status_db_script="/var/lib/dpkg/dpkg-sync-status-db"
    _dpkg_sync_status_db_script_generator() {
        printf "%s\\n" "#!/bin/sh"
        printf "%s\\n" "#autogenerated by ${package}: $(date +%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M)"
        printf "\\n"
        printf "%s\\n" '##close stdout'
        printf "%s\\n" '#exec 1<&-'
        printf "%s\\n" '##close stderr'
        printf "%s\\n" '#exec 2<&-'
        printf "%s\\n" '##open stdout as $log_file file for read and write.'
        printf "%s\\n" "#exec 1<> /tmp/${package}.\${$}.debug"
        printf "%s\\n" '##redirect stderr to stdout'
        printf "%s\\n" '#exec 2>&1'
        printf "%s\\n" '#set -x #enable trace mode'
        printf "\\n"
        printf "%s\\n" "while fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done"
        printf "\\n"
        printf "%s\\n" 'pkgs__add="$(cat /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue)"'
        printf "%s\\n" 'if [ -n "${pkgs__add}" ]; then'
        printf "%s\\n" '  for pkg in $pkgs__add; do'
        printf "%s\\n" '    if ! busybox grep "^Package: ${pkg}$" /var/lib/dpkg/status >/dev/null 2>&1; then'
        printf "%s\\n" '      busybox sed -n "/Package: ${pkg}$/,/^$/p" \'
        printf "%s\\n" "      /var/lib/dpkg/status-append-queue >> /var/lib/dpkg/status"
        printf "%s\\n" "    fi"
        printf "%s\\n" "  done"
        printf "%s\\n" "fi"
        printf "\\n"
        printf "%s\\n" 'pkgs__rm="$(cat /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue)"'
        printf "%s\\n" 'if [ -n "${pkgs__rm}" ]; then'
        printf "%s\\n" '  for pkg in $pkgs__rm; do'
        printf "%s\\n" '    busybox sed -i "/Package: ${pkg}$/,/^$/d" /var/lib/dpkg/status'
        printf "%s\\n" "  done"
        printf "%s\\n" "fi"
        printf "\\n"
        printf "%s\\n" "mv /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue.bk"
        printf "%s\\n" "mv /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue  /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue.bk"
        printf "%s\\n" "mv /var/lib/dpkg/status-append-queue /var/lib/dpkg/status-append-queue.bk"
        printf "\\n"
        printf "%s\\n" "rm -rf /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue"
        printf "%s\\n" "rm -rf ${_dpkg_sync_status_db_script}"
    }

    _dpkg_sync_status_db_script_generator > "${_dpkg_sync_status_db_script}"
    chmod +x "${_dpkg_sync_status_db_script}"
    _daemonize /bin/sh -c "${_dpkg_sync_status_db_script}"
}

_daemonize() {
    #http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-145.html
    [ -z "${1}" ] && return 1
    (   #1. fork, to guarantee the child is not a process
        #group leader, necessary for setsid) and have the
        #parent exit (to allow control to return to the shell)

        #2. redirect stdin/stdout/stderr before running child
        [ -t 0 ] && exec  </dev/null
        [ -t 1 ] && exec  >/dev/null
        [ -t 2 ] && exec 2>/dev/null
        if ! command -v "setsid" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            #2.1 guard against HUP and INT (in child)
            trap '' 1 2
        fi

        #3. ensure cwd isn't a mounted fs so it does't block
        #umo unt invocations
        cd /

        #4. umask (leave this to caller)
        #umask 0

        #5. close unneeded fds
        #XCU 2.7 Redirection says: open files are represented by
        #decimal numbers starting with zero. The largest possible
        #value is implementation-defined; however, all
        #implementations shall support at least 0 to 9, inclusive,
        #for use by the application.
        i=3; while [ "${i}" -le "9" ]; do
            eval "exec ${i}>&-"
            i="$(($i + 1))"
        done

        #6. create new session, so the child has no
        #controlling terminal, this prevents the child from
        #accesing a terminal (using /dev/tty) and getting
        #signals from the controlling terminal (e.g. HUP, INT)
        if command -v "setsid" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            exec setsid "$@"
        elif command -v "nohup" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            exec nohup "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1
        else
            if [ ! -f "${1}" ]; then
                "$@"
            else
                exec "$@"
            fi
        fi
    ) &
    #2.2 guard against HUP (in parent)
    if ! command -v "setsid" >/dev/null 2>&1 \ &&
       ! command -v "nohup"  >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        disown -h "${!}"
    fi
}

_apt_add_queue() {
    for pkg in "${@}"; do
        if  busybox grep "${pkg}" /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            busybox sed -i "/^${pkg}$/d" /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue
        else
            if ! busybox grep "^Package: ${pkg}$" /var/lib/dpkg/status >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                printf "%s\\n" "${pkg}" >> /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue
            fi
        fi
    done; unset pkg
}

_apt_rm_queue() {
    for pkg in "${@}"; do
        if  busybox grep "${pkg}" /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            busybox sed -i "/^${pkg}$/d" /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue
        else
            if busybox grep "^Package: ${pkg}$" /var/lib/dpkg/status >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                printf "%s\\n" "${pkg}" >> /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue
            fi
        fi
    done; unset pkg
}

_apt_install() {
    [ -z "${1}" ] && return
    _apt_add_queue $(printf "%s\\n" "${@}" | busybox sed "s:${package}::g")
}

_apt_purge() {
    [ -z "${1}" ] && return
    _apt_rm_queue $(printf "%s\\n" "${@}" | busybox sed "s:${package}::g")
}

_apt_run() {
    [ ! -f /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue ] && [ ! -f /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue ] && return

    pkgs__add="$(cat /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue 2>/dev/null)"
    if [ -n "${pkgs__add}" ]; then
        _dpkg_suspend_process
        busybox awk '/^Package: /{print $2}' /var/lib/dpkg/status | \
            busybox sort > /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs.orig
        _apt_run__output="$(DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install  \
            --no-install-recommends -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" \
            -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --force-yes ${pkgs__add} 2>&1)" || \
            printf "%s\\n" "${_apt_run__output}" >&2
        busybox awk '/^Package: /{print $2}' /var/lib/dpkg/status | \
            busybox sort > /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs.current
        _dpkg__added_pkgs="$(busybox diff -Naur /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs.orig \
            /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs.current | busybox awk '/^\+[a-zA-Z]/{gsub("^+","");print;}')"
        busybox rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs*
        #add dependencies
        if [ -n "${_dpkg__added_pkgs}" ]; then
            printf "%s\\n" "${_dpkg__added_pkgs}" >> /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue
            printf "%s\\n" "$(busybox sort /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue | busybox uniq)" \
                > /var/lib/apt/apt-add-queue
        fi

        #extract dpkg status output to append it at the end
        for pkg in $_dpkg__added_pkgs; do
            busybox sed -n '/Package: '"${pkg}"'$/,/^$/p' /var/lib/dpkg/status \
                >> /var/lib/dpkg/status-append-queue
        done
        _dpkg_continue_process
    fi

    pkgs__rm="$(cat /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue 2>/dev/null)"
    if [ -n "${pkgs__rm}" ]; then
        _dpkg_suspend_process
        busybox awk '/^Package: /{print $2}' /var/lib/dpkg/status | \
            busybox sort > /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs.orig
        _apt_run__output="$(DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get purge \
            -y ${pkgs__rm} 2>&1)" || printf "%s\\n" "${_apt_run__output}" >&2
        busybox awk '/^Package: /{print $2}' /var/lib/dpkg/status | \
            busybox sort > /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs.current
        _dpkg__removed_pkgs="$(busybox diff -Naur /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs.orig \
            /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs.current | busybox awk '/^-[a-zA-Z]/{gsub("^-","");print;}')"
        busybox rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/status-pkgs*
        #remove dependencies
        if [ -n "${_dpkg__removed_pkgs}" ]; then
            printf "%s\\n" "${_dpkg__removed_pkgs}" >> /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue
            printf "%s\\n" "$(busybox sort /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue | busybox uniq)" \
                > /var/lib/apt/apt-rm-queue
        fi
        _dpkg_continue_process
    fi

    _dpkg_sync_status_db
}

_apt_install foo bar
_apt_purge   ugly packages
_apt_run
```

Comment: ***YOU SHOULD NEVER MOVE THOSE LOCK FILES UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING***.  Removing the locks while other package stuff is going on could damange the system.  Also, what is this "script" supposed to do?  I don't see how it answers the OP's question.

Comment: It's an implementation of the response description, it provides functions which the OP could use on its maintainer scripts to install/remove software within its debian package, just what the OP asked for.